# Why doesn't MSSQL doesn't support `CHARACTER SET` specified as part of the `CREATE DATABASE` statement?

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm used to operate MySQL databases, where the `CHARACTER SET` is (optionally) specified as part of the `CREATE DATABASE` statement together with the `COLLATION`:

```
engine.execute(f'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {db} CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

However, for MSSQL I can only specify the `COLLATION`:

```
engine.execute(f'CREATE DATABASE {db} COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC')
```

Why is it not possible to specify the `CHARACTER SET`, when creating databases for MSSQL?

Comment: Because SQL Server doesn't work the same as MySQL. Collation includes both the rules for comparing strings and (implicitly) the encoding used (for `VARCHAR`; `NVARCHAR` always uses UTF-16).

Comment: Note that UTF-8 support (introduced in SQL Server 2019) has inflated the number of collations dramatically because of this: most now have a `_UTF8` variant that uses UTF-8 rather than the "native" encoding for that collation.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - so, SQL Server collations also include a specific character set? Isn't that very inflexible? Why do you refer to character set as **encoding**?

Comment: It's not particularly inflexible, just clumsy. The collation rules must apply to all supported characters; this means that separating collations and character sets entirely isn't possible in the first place. In SQL Server, the collation defines *all* of these things: the comparison rules (collation), the character set (which characters can be stored) *and* the encoding (the way characters are stored as binary code points). "Character set" and "encoding" are related, but not precisely the same; MySQL arguably uses the term incorrectly (`utf8mb4` and `utf16` allow for the same characters).

Comment: And again, note that for `NVARCHAR`, the collation really does only specify collation rules and not the character set or the encoding ("every Unicode character" and "UTF-16", respectively); only for `VARCHAR` does the collation also dictate that.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by *MySQL arguably uses the term incorrectly (utf8mb4 and utf16 allow for the same characters)*?

Comment: A character set is, literally, the set of all characters supported. These are the same for both `utf8mb4` and `utf16` (both support all Unicode characers) so these are *not* distinct character sets. They *are* different encodings, though (different bytes are used to encode the same characters). Therefore, what MySQL calls a character set should have been properly called an encoding. MySQL is by far not the only product to use the terms loosely, though, because typically character sets and encodings are closely related (the encoding dictates the character set).

Answer (score 1):

There is a close and reciprocal relationship between the collation and the character set. Some collation can be proposed in some character set but not some other. Mixing all character sets and collations is not possible.
Microsoft SQL Server made the choice of simplicity in giving the most widespread possibilities by collation that induces character set.
It is why, actually, MS SQL Server have the most complete character/collation choice over all databases of the world...

To do so, there is 2 famillies of COLLATIONS :

- collations for semantic exploitation of the data, called "Windows    Collations" and corresponding to an ASCII/UNICODE generic character set
- collations for technical exploitation of the data, called "SQL    collations" and corresponding to specific character sets (those    collations are nammed by the "SQL_" prefix.)

SQL collations are used essentially to import data without any loss of special characters when you have a file with a particular character encoding.

So CREATE DATABASE only support COLLATION as a part of the statement, that induces character set.

Comment: Just to be accurate : a CHARACTER SET is encoding (physical level), while collation rules the behaviour of strings at the logical level.